# Reverse Related entries with Matrix Field

Tags: matrix, relations

I have a site with channels *‘articles’* and *‘tutorials.’* An article entry has a matrix field which contains an entry field to link to a tutorial. Every tutorial is linked from within at least one article.

I would like each tutorial page to link back to the articles it appears in.

If I'm on a tutorial page and have the following code in my template…

```
{% set articles = craft.entries.section('articles').relatedTo(entry) %}
{{ articles|length }}
```

articles|length is always zero.

I did a test with just a simple entry field to link to a tutorial and that works fine. Is there something special that needs to be done to get it to work with a matrix field? Could it be a configuration issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the 'Going Through Matrix' section at http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param.

```
{% set articles = craft.entries.section('articles').relatedTo({
    targetElement: entry,
    field: 'myMatrixField.fieldHandle'
}) %}
```

Comment: This works. Thanks.

I thought I had tried this and it didn't work, but I must have slipped the block type handle in there along with the field handle.